# Centre latitude & longitude of a geography polygon region in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, geospatial

I have a geographic polygon created as follows

```
DECLARE @polyString as varchar(max);
SET @polyString = 'POLYGON((' + @eastAsString + ' ' + @northAsString +',' + @westAsString + ' ' + @northAsString + ',' + @westAsString + ' '+@southAsString +','+ @eastAsString + ' ' + @southAsString +',' +@eastAsString +' ' +@northAsString +'))';

DECLARE @g geography;
SET @g = geography::STPolyFromText(@polyString, 4326)
```

I would like to find the centre lat/long of the polygon? Is this possible inside sql server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `EnvelopeCenter()` method of the `geography` type.

```
DECLARE @polyString as varchar(max);
SET @polyString = 'POLYGON((' + @eastAsString + ' ' + @northAsString +',' + @westAsString + ' ' + @northAsString + ',' + @westAsString + ' '+@southAsString +','+ @eastAsString + ' ' + @southAsString +',' +@eastAsString +' ' +@northAsString +'))';

DECLARE @g geography;
SET @g = geography::STPolyFromText(@polyString, 4326)
SELECT @g.EnvelopeCenter().ToString()
```

It would be helpful to define what exactly you mean by center of the polygon, because there are different ways of defining it.

Comment: thankyou for your reply.I was looking for the centre of the polygon from the view point of looking at a 2-dimensional map, then when i draw a rectangle region on the map I would like to know the centre point of this region ie its lat/long co-ordinates.

Comment: You mean draw a rectangle around the polygon, like you'd take the center of the minimal bounding rectangle of the polygon?

Comment: yes the minimal bounding rectangle of the polygon is what I am looking for.

Comment: you can do this without the geography type. if you know the lat/lon, you can just take the min/max of each of those and take averages of the min/max lat/lon pairs.

Comment: If you're talking about calculating the centre of the polygon as it appears on a 2-d map, you really need to use the geometry datatype rather than the geography datatype, which treats spatial data as being defined on a curved 3-dimensional surface. If your polygons are all, in fact, regular 4-sided axis-aligned rectangles, then the EnvelopeCenter() method should be sufficient though.